# Check for update on Google Play for particular application in phone-gap (android)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a button (Check for update) in my phone-gap android application. I want to redirect to the Google play store with the my app and if there is any update there should be the update button. Expected output is shown in below image.

[image]

I have used :-

```
 window.location.href = "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appName";
     and
 window.location.href = "market://details?id=com.appName"; //Does not work
```

But I am getting the output in below image :-

[image]

Is there any plugin or any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no plugins for achive this(i suppose).Here is the method we are using in one of our projects

1.Every time app launches setup background ajax request to check to see if update is avaliable.

2.if available set the update button is visible otherwise hide the button.

```
$.ajax({
url:'www.example.com/check_for_update.php?action=update',
success:function(data){
   if(data){
   //update is avaliable
   $('#updatediv').show();
  }else{
  //no update avaliable
  $('#updatediv').hide();
}

});
```

in your php file

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])=='update'){

//if update avaliable set $isUpdate to true
//default value is false
$isUpdate=false;
echo $isUpdate;

}
```

html part

```
<div id="updatediv">
  <button on-click="window.location.href = "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appName">Update</button>
</div>
```

Actually in our app there is web admin part.if an update is avaliable admin will publish there is an update is avaliable(ie value of $isUpadate deponds on admin's action).
I dont know its correct way,but this will work fine for us.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inAppBrowser plugin

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Ad then open your app link with system, user will select Playstore or browser to open your app page.

```
window.open('http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appName',"_system");
```

This is basic. But if you want to make sure that actually an update is avalable or not, just keep a page  in online server with latest version. Call that page, bring the version with ajax call as shammon described. Check with your app version. If there is an update version available then call your app page with inAppBrowser or show message that current version is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this :

JS Part

```
function do_update(){
    window.location.replace('market://details?id=com.appName');
}
```

HTML Part

```
<input type="button" id="btnUpdate" value="Update" onclick="do_update();"/>
```

After the button be pressed, it will redirect to google play